# VB.net Second String Found getbetween

Tags: vb.net, substring

i have a function that give me the text between two words:

```
Private Shared Function GetBetween(ByRef strSource As String, ByRef strStart As String, ByRef strEnd As String, Optional ByRef startPos As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim iPos As Integer, iEnd As Integer, lenStart As Integer = strStart.Length
    Dim strResult As String
    strResult = String.Empty
    iPos = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, startPos)
    iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, iPos + lenStart)
    If iPos <> -1 AndAlso iEnd <> -1 Then
        strResult = strSource.Substring(iPos + lenStart, iEnd - (iPos + lenStart))
    End If
    Return strResult
End Function
```

So my html code is:

```
<div class="upper-right-section">
            <div class="header-stats">


    <div class="stat-entry">
        <span class="stat-value">48998</span>
  <span class="stat-name">iscritti</span>

    </div>



    <div class="stat-entry">
        <span class="stat-value">22760801</span>
  <span class="stat-name">visualizzazioni video</span>

    </div>

  </div>

          <span class="valign-shim"></span>
        </div>
```

I got two times `<span class="stat-value">` and i want to get the value of second match, how can i do? thanks, matteo.

Comment: Use [**Html Agilty Pack**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: +1 for the HAP. And the function is defunct: StartPos is passed by ref, but not set to the found position. Otherwise you could simply call the function 2 times. Set StartPos to the index of the found string inside the function and you are done. Still better use the **HAP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general html parsing, HAP or CSQuery are great, however if this is an isolated case in your program, and you are confident the html source will remain the same, you can use the following:

```
Dim value As String = Split(Split(theHtmlStringHere, "<span class=""stat-value"">")(2), "</span>")(0)
```